# Shape of passed values is (2, 1), indices imply (1, 1)..What could be the reason?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Input: `X.Columns`

Output: `Index(['No of Establishements', 'No of places secured'], dtype='object')`

Input: `lm.coef_`

Output: `array([[20.0695058,  0.2924545]])`

Input: `pd.DataFrame(lm.coef_,X.columns,columns = ['Coeff'])`

Output: `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2, 1), indices imply (1, 1)`

Please refer the above statements written in python, I was trying to create a dataframe. But getting value error. Please help to come out of it.

Comment: i think you got you parameters in the wrong order, try `pd.DataFrame(X.columns, lm.coef_, columns = ['Coeff'])`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need select values of `coef_` for 1d array:

```
pd.DataFrame(lm.coef_[0],X.columns,columns = ['Coeff'])
```